# Applicative functor laws violation

Tags: haskell, applicative

Excersize from an online course.

Suppose, that for a standard list Applicative functor the `<*>` operator is defined in a standard way, while `pure` is changed to

```
pure x = [x,x]
```

What laws of Applicative typeclass will be violated?

- Homomorphism: `pure g <*> pure x ≡ pure (g x)`
- Identity: `pure id <*> xs ≡ xs`
- Interchange: `fs <*> pure x ≡ pure ($ x) <*> fs`
- Applicative-Functor: `g <$> xs ≡ pure g <*> xs`
- Composition: `(.) <$> us <*> vs <*> xs ≡ us <*> (vs <*> xs)`

I created the following file:

```
newtype MyList a = MyList {getMyList :: [a]}
  deriving Show

instance Functor MyList where
  fmap f (MyList xs) = MyList (map f xs)

instance Applicative MyList where
  pure x = MyList [x,x]
  MyList gs <*> MyList xs = MyList ([g x | g <- gs, x <- xs])

fs = MyList [\x -> 2*x, \x -> 3*x]
xs = MyList [1,2]
x = 1
g = (\x -> 2*x)
us = MyList [(\x -> 2*x)]
vs = MyList [(\x -> 3*x)]
```

Then I tried:

Homomorphism: `pure g <*> pure x ≡ pure (g x)`

```
*Main> pure g <*> pure x :: MyList Integer
MyList {getMyList = [2,2,2,2]}
*Main> pure (g x) :: MyList Integer
MyList {getMyList = [2,2]}
```

Identity: `pure id <*> xs ≡ xs`

```
*Main> pure id <*> xs :: MyList Integer
MyList {getMyList = [1,2,1,2]}
*Main> xs :: MyList Integer
MyList {getMyList = [1,2]}
```

Interchange: `fs <*> pure x ≡ pure ($ x) <*> fs`

```
*Main> fs <*> pure x
[2,3]
*Main> pure ($ x) <*> fs
[2,3]
```

Applicative-Functor: `g <$> xs ≡ pure g <*> xs`

```
*Main> g <$> xs
MyList {getMyList = [2,4]}
*Main> pure g <*> xs
MyList {getMyList = [2,4,2,4]}
```

Composition: `(.) <$> us <*> vs <*> xs ≡ us <*> (vs <*> xs)`

```
*Main> (.) <$> us <*> vs <*> xs
MyList {getMyList = [6,12]}
*Main> us <*> (vs <*> xs)
MyList {getMyList = [6,12]}
```

Composition shouldn't be violated, because `pure` is not used here.

It seems that Homomorphism, Identity and Applicative-Functor don't work. But when I select them in the course, it says that the answer is wrong. So, who is the fool: me or the author of the course?

Comment: You didn't test MyList in the interchange example.  Look at how the results are being printed compared to all the other examples.

Comment: the absence of noise is also a signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @DavidFletcher's comment, using your code, I see different output for the interchange test:

```
> fs <*> pure x
MyList {getMyList = [2,2,3,3]}
> pure ($ x) <*> fs
MyList {getMyList = [2,3,2,3]}
```

so you might want to double-check that one.

Comment: My God, seems that I was testing it for the ordinary list. The exercise is solved now, thank you.